# how to get all the properties of a user control [Grid view]

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have  developed  a  gridview   control. which as  searching, paging ,sorting, as a   Functionality.  i have   made this  control as   a  user  control. in the  page  where  i am using   the user  control. i need to add check box inside the  user  control[GRIDVIEW].

right now  i am  assigning the  bound  fields  like this

```
<uc1:GridUserControl ID="GridUserControl1" runat="server" Header1 ="User " Datafield1 ="User_Name" Header2="First Name" Datafield2 ="First_Name" Header3 ="Last Name" Datafield3 ="Last_Name"  />
```

now  is there  any  way  we can  add   our  control's  inside the   User  control [gridview ]

can  any one  let me  know   how  to achive this

thank  you

Comment: "right now i am assigning the bound fields like this" - Looks like you meant to put a code sample in here, but missed it. Can you explain what you're currently doing?

Comment: right now  i am  assigning the  bound  fields  like this


<uc1:GridUserControl ID="GridUserControl1" runat="server" Header1 ="User " Datafield1 ="User_Name" Header2="First Name" Datafield2 ="First_Name" Header3 ="Last Name" Datafield3 ="Last_Name"  />

Comment: i  dnt  want to  create  check box  control in my user  control.  i  want to create the  button, check box  control  in the page  where i am using the   user  control  .

it is much like   i am creating an template  like  where  searching, storing, paging is  done  on  all the pages.   where  i am  use  my  grid user  control.

 but  adding  button ,check box  for the    gridview  should be    inside the  user  control.  because in  some page   i want  to add  check box  column, and  in some page i need  to  add  link  button   cloumn in  user  control  grid

Comment: it is like    add ing  check box,link button,  to the  user  control grid at the  page where  we  are  using    user  control

Answer (score 1):

You can get at a usercontrol's child controls using

```
myUserControlInstance.FindControl("ChildControlID")
```

but you probably don't want to. This is rather fragile, due to the lack of compile-time checking. If the control was renamed (or refactored into another control for reuse),this would start failing at runtime.

I recommend either a property on the user control that exposes the checkbox, or enough properties/methods on the user control to set the checkbox's state.

You may also want to consider why the parents need to know about the innards of the usercontrol. I usually treat a control's children as analogous to private/protected methods on a class. Hide the implementation details, so you can change them if required!